# Preventing structs from being collected while passing their pointers to C calls

Tags: go, pointers, memory, garbage-collection, ffi

I'm writing a program which needs to call a number of C functions. These functions require pointers to structs, which are allocated by me. I know I can't simply convert and pass `uintptr`s because they hold no semantic value, thus the GC may take my structs away.

So, in order to keep GC from collecting my structs, I came up with this:

```
type Person struct {
    thing uint32
    other uint32
}

// Keeps pointers from being collected.
// Note this is a global variable.
var people map[*Person]struct{}

// Creates one or more structs.
func createPeople() (p1, p2 *Person) {
    p1 = &Person{name: "John"}
    people[p1] = struct{}{} // keep

    p2 = &Person{name: "Mary"}
    people[p2] = struct{}{} // keep

    return
}

// Cleanup.
func deletePeople() {
    for k := range people {
        delete(people, k)
    }
}

func main() {
    people = make(map[*Person]struct{})
    p1, p2 := createPeople()

    // Lots of calls to C functions passing people pointers.
    rawP1 := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(p1))
    ffiCall(rawP1)

    deletePeople() // mandatory?
}
```

Will the solution above work?

Is there any risk of the structs being moved, thus messing up the pointers?

What if I **don't call** `deletePeople()`?

Comment: Go *currently* does not have a moving (compacting etc) collector, but I don't think there are any promises about this in the future. For strict safety, pass C pointers to C, using `C.malloc` and `C.free` as needed.